# Change the video file that is being streamed with Node.js

Tags: html, node.js, web, stream, mp4

## My question

I want to create a viewer in Node.js that supports playback for multiple videos.

[The reference link describes the playback method for a single video.](https://betterprogramming.pub/video-stream-with-node-js-and-html5-320b3191a6b6)

Specifically, I want to use a pull-down menu to switch between video files stored in a directory and display them in HTML.

I have tried to change the path of the video according to the selection in the pull-down menu, but the following error occurred.

```
RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "start" is out of range. It must be <= "end"
```

How can this be resolved?
Is there a need to process once piped() to unpipe()?

## Orginal Code

I`m using Nodejs and EJS.

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var glob = require("glob")
var express = require("express");

const port = 3000;
var app = express();
var videoPath = "";

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('./sample.ejs', {
        files: mp4files = glob.sync("video/*.mp4"),
        path: videoPath,
    });
});

app.get('/renderVideo', function (req, res) {
    const path = videoPath
    const stat = fs.statSync(path)
    const fileSize = stat.size
    const range = req.headers.range
    if (range) {
        const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")
        const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10)
        const end = parts[1]
            ? parseInt(parts[1], 10)
            : fileSize - 1
        const chunksize = (end - start) + 1
        const file = fs.createReadStream(path, { start, end })
        const head = {
            'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
            'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
            'Content-Length': chunksize,
            'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
        }
        res.writeHead(206, head);
        file.pipe(res);

    } else {
        const head = {
            'Content-Length': fileSize,
            'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
        }
        res.writeHead(200, head)
        fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res)
    }
});

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.post('/getMp4Name', function (req, res) {
    videoPath = req.body.mp4
    res.redirect("/")
    console.log("videoPath : ", videoPath)
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log('app listening on port 3000!'))
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <title>Test Application</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- get mp4 files list -->
    <div>
        <form method="POST" id="tableForm" action="/getMp4Name">
            <select class="mp4" name="mp4">
                <% for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++){ %>
                    <option value=<%=files[i] %> ><%=files[i] %>
                    </option>
                    <%} %>
            </select>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- show Mp4 -->
    <figure>
        <video id="displayVideo" controls style="max-width: 500px;">
            <source src="http://localhost:3000/renderVideo/" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
    </figure>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Show code of how you select a file and how you play a video. You need to reset something somewhere...

Comment: I added my original code.

Comment: I was hoping a NodeJS user would answer you by now... Anyways the error tells you that your `end` number **is smaller** than your `start` number. Is there anyway to reset your numbers at each _"pull-down menu to switch between video files"_? Or else have some code to **re-run the function that fetches** the file's bytes, with each fetch starting from `0` up to `filesize - 1`?.